# Creating an JavaScript array from Input boxes. Text and integers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I will have some sort of form on the page and will need to save the values into an array to run through an algorithm. Any ideas how i could do this. Had a quick google search to no avail.

Comment: Loop through the fields and build an array. What's the issue?

Answer (score 3):

How about...

```
var arr = $( '.inputs' ).map( function () { return $( this ).val(); }).get();
```